# ZF2 An Invalid Factory Was Registered

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules, zend-form2

I've the following classes and my module config in ZF2 application and it is giving the below error:

```
While attempting to create applicationformuserform(alias: Application\Form
\UserForm) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.
```

**UserFormFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Factory\Form;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Form\UserForm;

class UserFormFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $services         = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $entityManager    = $services->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        $form = new UserForm($entityManager);

        return $form;
    }
}

?>
```

**UserForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class UserForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'User Name',
                ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'first_name',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'First Name',
                ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'last_name',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type'  => 'text',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Last Name',
                ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'role_id',
                'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                'options' => array(
                        'object_manager'     => $this->entityManager,
                        'target_class'       => 'Application\Entity\Role',
                        'property' => 'id',
                        'is_method' => true,
                        'find_method'        => array(
                                'name'   => 'getRoles',
                        ),
                        'label' => 'User Role',
                ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(); // filter and validation here
    }
}

?>
```

**Module.config.php**

```
'form_elements' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'Application\Form\UserForm' => 'Application\Factory\Form\UserFormFactory',
            ),
    ),
```

And I'm using this form factory in another controller factory

**UserControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Member\Factory\Controller;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Member\Controller\UserController;
use Application\Form\UserForm;

class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $services    = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $userForm    = $services->get('FormElementManager')->get('Application\Form\UserForm');

        $controller  = new UserController($userForm);

        return $controller;
    }
}

?>
```

Could anybody tell me that what may be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that **UserFormFactory.php** is located under `Application\Factory\Form` directory?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is there

Comment: take a look on `public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)` - you try to call `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()`, but this variable already has `ServiceLocatorInterface`

Comment: You have to doublecheck your folder structure, file naming (case sensitive) and autoloading setup. I'm 99% sure this is an autoloading issue.

Comment: @RodinVasiliy The method signature is the same as `FactoryInterface` provides. It's good pratice to rename `$serviceLocator` to `$controllerManager` in this case, so it's clear you are dealing with the controllermanager here. Anyway, calling `getServiceLocator()` here is correct and not the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: @BramGerritsen You are great man. My folder structure was wrong by mistake. Now its working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my answer at my own after looking at the code again and again. Actually my **Factory** and **Form** folders were outside of **src** folder that's why Zend could not found all the classes of both folders.

I moved both Factory and Form folder in src and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 8):

Your Factory is not being found.

Check if you using PSR-4 or PSR-0 in your controller among the other answers

Briefly

- did you name the Factory correctly (no misspellings)?
- Is your composer.json updated with PSR-0, or PSR-4 namespaces for your modules?
- did you run `composer dump-autoload`?
- Does your `autoload_classmap.php` contain an outdated entry & confuses autoloader?
- Check your folder structure and names
- make sure your Factory `implements FactoryInterface`

Ask yourself "Why is my Factory class not being found when I have placed it right there" where it obviously without a doubt must be found?  That will help you guide your way into finding out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I had made some changes to my factory classes (refactoring + minor class name changes).  Turns out that because I was using the Classmap Autoloader ... and forgot to re-run php vendor/bin/classmap_generator.php in the module structure ... the newly renamed classes were not found.  Too bad a "class not found" error wasn't generated.